# Add new item with multiple properties in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I'm trying to add a new item to an observable array when a button is clicked. I'm pretty much following this example on the knockout.js site:
http://knockoutjs.com/examples/betterList.html

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<form data-bind="submit:addItem">
    <input id="comment" data-bind="value:itemToAdd.comment, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save contact" />
</form>
```

As you can see (this is the difference from the example), my "itemToAdd" will have multiple properties, one of them is "comment". So I'm trying to bind it like this: "value:itemToAdd.comment" (I also tried "value:itemToAdd().comment"). But that doesn't seem to work. Here's the relevant part of my view model:

```
var viewModel = {


     contactHistory: [{comment: 'test', date: '12/12/2011'}, {comment: 'test2', date: '12/11/2011'}],

    itemToAdd: new ko.observable({ comment: 'dd', date: '' }),

    addItem: function () {
            alert(this.itemToAdd().comment);
                if (this.itemToAdd().comment != "")
                {
                    this.contactHistory.push(this.itemToAdd());
                }
            }
}
```

The alert always displays "dd", so the itemToAdd doesn't seem to be properly bound to the text box. Does anyone haven an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

normally you would do `itemToAdd().comment`, but KO actually isn't able to write properly when the property in the data-bind is not an observable and is nested.

You can certainly solve it by making `comment` an observable like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/mFkGT/.  You would not need to have `itemToAdd` be an observable in that case, if you didn't want it to be.

Another option would be to get into the scope of `itemToAdd` before binding against `comment`.  In 1.3, you could use a `with: itemToAdd` like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/SDAhd/.  If you don't want the extra span, then you can use a containerless binding like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ZmDwW/.

Prior to 1.3, you could use the template binding with a `data` parameter to do something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/sb6vD/

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned in my original question that I tried value: itemToAdd().comment as well. Do you see anything else that could be wrong?

Comment: I see.  KO does have a problem writing to a nested non-observable.  Updated answer with some options that you have.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Really helped me. Too bad I can only upvote once :)